# Explanation of $x\in\mathbb{N}^{+}_{0}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

Is this the way to explain what I mean with $x\in\mathbb{N}^{+}_{0}$:

$$x\in\mathbb{N}^{+}_{0}\rightarrow x\in\mathbb{R},x>0$$

Or is there a different better way to explain it?

I want so say that $x$ is a real number and bigger than zero

Comment: Hint:  If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ it can be not integer...

Comment: While the implication seems fine, I would have expected $x\in\mathbb N$ on the right side. But what is the supposed differenece between $\Bbb N_0^+$ and $\Bbb N$?

Comment: @EmilioNovati What? $1\in\Bbb R$. $\Bbb R$ is the set of real numbers, not the set of irrationals.

Comment: Maybe that you want $x\in\mathbb{Z}_0^+$? .... this has more sense :)

Comment: I say that it can be *not integer* not that it cannot be an integer. $\pi \in \mathbb{R}$ is not integer.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Sorry, misread.

Comment: You should consider using words rather than symbols to say what $x$ must or must not be. That will help both your reader and yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb N$ is ambiguous. There are some who use it to mean $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$, and there are some who use it to mean $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$. I've seen people use $\Bbb N_0$ to refer to the former, and $\Bbb N_+$ to refer to the latter, but only rarely. Generally, people say which one they want $\Bbb N$ to mean and stick with it.

If you want to refer to the positive reals, $(0,\infty)$ works. (You can also use the French interval notation $]0,\infty[$. Alternatively, you can use $\Bbb R_+$ or $\Bbb R_{>0}$.)

If you want to refer to the nonnegative reals, $[0,\infty)$ works. (Again, the French notation would be $[0,\infty[$. You can also use $\Bbb R_{\ge0}$.)